# Where is the second directive in this book statement

Tags: angular, directive

Hi I m reading  a book about angular

I got the following sentence dipicted below

[image]

For me it is entuitive that the ngFor is a structural directive. But where is the second one ?

Thanks

Comment: I believe the book is wrong, the *ngFor is the only structural directive there!

Comment: and please why downvoting ?

Comment: not sure if you're asking me, but I wasn't the one to downvote it :P

Comment: It can't be someone one this thread. lately I feel like getting harrased by someone , All my last 4 question are getting downvoted without getting any reason. I just sent a request to sof team to check if it is true.

Comment: I see, I'm sorry to hear that, I hope it's just a coincidence :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed two types of directives.

`1) Structural Directives`

`2) Attribute Directives`

But in this example there is only one directive used and this is the `*ngFor`. This is responsible for creating an `li` element for every object of the `books` array.

The attribute directive is a type of directive that can be applied to an existing element. This allows you to change the attributes of the element. Something like you can take the index at each iteration and then pass it into the attribute directive, and once based on a condition with the index you can format the `li` element by changing its attributes such as the CSS Styling through the attribute directive.

I have attached an example use of the Attribute Directive

1. Directive Class

   `import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit } from "@angular/core";`

   ```
    @Directive({
      selector:'[appHighlight]'
    })
    export class HighlightText implements OnInit{
      private theReference : ElementRef

      constructor(theReference : ElementRef){
        this.theReference = theReference;
      }
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.theReference.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = "lightcoral";
      }
    }
   ```
2. Usage in Template

`<p appHighlight>Directive Usage</p>`

When the directive is referenced as an attribute using selector `[appHighlight]`, in the element `<p>` the attribute defined in the directive `backgroundColor` in the `OnInit` hook. You can change the attribute you want to change using the `Renderer2` or by accessing the `nativeElement` property, though it is recommended to use the `Renderer2`

Comment: Thank you so the book is some.how faulty in it statement.

Answer (score 1):

`*ngFor` <-- notice the
`*`. Directives prefixed with `*` are usually shorthands of other directives (usually two directives "merged" into a single one).

Angular transforms the *ngFor from asterisk (`*`) syntax to `<ng-template>` element.
Take a look at this code:

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
  {{hero.name}}
</div>
```

It's just like doing:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-hero [ngForOf]="heroes">
  <div>{{hero.name}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

I suggest to take a look at the [structural directives with the asterisk prefix](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-asterisk--prefix)

Comment: GBra, please check better the image, it says "two structural directives", not "two directives" in general

Comment: sorry Dario, I am not sure I understand your point here: Structural directives are responsible for HTML layout. They shape or reshape the DOM's structure, typically by adding, removing, or manipulating elements. We use two structural directives there: [ngFor] and [ngForOf]. Do you think that one of the two is an attribute directive? An Attribute directive changes the appearance or behavior of a DOM element. So I guess both are structural.

Comment: Hi GBra, I can understand this being a bit of a confusing argument, but I do believe that only *ngFor is technically the only structural directive there and ngForOf is an attribute directory. Since as you pointed out structural directives have the asterisk prefix. Moreover the official docs (https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives) do say that "You may apply only one structural directive to an element.", so yes I do not think that both are structural directives. What are your thoughts on that? :)

Comment: this thing is tricky, I believe that the book is wrong in this point may be an errata. I can't understand logically where is the second element that is updating the dom other then the *ngFor (it is true that I m not that guru on angular but trying to be) my personal though is that the only thing that is updating the dom is ngFor somehow I feel that [ngForOf] is more model related precisely a one way biding that fetches a value from a set of values, there will be no dom update without ngFor. I still believe there is ONLY One Directive

Comment: @Dario: as you say "You may apply only one structural directive to an element". For this exact purpose, I am considering that as two structural directives. 1. directive is responsible to copy the entire HTML element and place inside the ng-template tag (so that you have the problem that I quoted aka more than 1 structural directive in one element)  2. another structural directive that copies the element inside ng-template as many time as it needs to be iterated and hydrates the element with the required data.
That being said, I am not 100% sure, shall we create another question about this?

Comment: Not sure it kind of feels like we're splitting hairs here, but if you're going to create the question feel free to link it here :)

Comment: Dario Piotrowicz, I agree with you that this is probably not a very important question, however, by digging even more in the Angular docs I've found another piece where it refers to [ngFor] and [ngForOf] both as directives (and states that one implements the other one). I find this a bit confusing for everybody, if I can get a detailed answer and understand, I might suggest a text change in the docs to make it clearer. Question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65763329/angular-ngfor-is-made-of-one-single-structural-directive-or-two/65763857